# Define External properties for application in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, tomcat8, paas, cloud-foundry

I am newbie to Cloud Foundry, trying to deploy application on CF. The application is Java/Tomcat based. I have application specific properties (database properties) externally (outside of war file). So, if I have to deploy my application in CF, how do I define all the external properties in CF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to inject the properties as environment variables. Popular approaches include:

1. Define the properties in your manifest.yml when you push the application: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block
2. Use Spring Cloud Config to manage these properties externally, and inject them on startup: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Comment: Is it possible to put external properties in Git repo and pass Git http url in manifest.yaml (or some other location) during my application deploy?

Comment: That is pretty much how Spring Cloud Config works, except that you will put the Git http URL into your application's properties file instead of the manifest.yml. See the documentation for Spring Cloud Config